# Python - sorting a list of tuples by an uneven list

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda

I have a deck of cards built by the following code:

```
import itertools

suits = "DCHS"
ranks = "23456789TJQKA"

cardDeck = list(set(itertools.product(ranks, suits)))
```

I want to sort the deck of card by ranks.
Doing a sorted(cardDeck, key=lambda x: x[0]) sorts the list by ranks alphabetically (23456789AJKQT) but I would like to find a way to maintain the order of ranks (23456789TJQKA).

I've been playing with trying to get a lambda function for the key= parameter that will iterate through the characters in the ranks string but so far I'm up against a wall. Maybe I need to make suits and ranks list of characters rather than strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the ranking in your `ranks` list. Just use that in your sorter:

```
print sorted(cardDeck, key=lambda x: ranks.index(x[0]))
```

You can see the [full thing here](https://ideone.com/nEHa0Q):

```
import itertools

suits = "DCHS"
ranks = "23456789TJQKA"

cardDeck = list(set(itertools.product(ranks, suits)))

print sorted(cardDeck, key=lambda x: ranks.index(x[0]))
```

Gives:

```
[('2', 'S'), ('2', 'C'), ('2', 'H'), ('2', 'D'), ('3', 'D'), ('3', 'H'), ('3', 'C'), ('3', 'S'), ('4', 'D'), ('4', 'S'), ('4', 'C'), ('4', 'H'), ('5', 'H'), ('5', 'S'), ('5', 'D'), ('5', 'C'), ('6', 'C'), ('6', 'D'), ('6', 'H'), ('6', 'S'), ('7', 'C'), ('7', 'D'), ('7', 'S'), ('7', 'H'), ('8', 'S'), ('8', 'C'), ('8', 'H'), ('8', 'D'), ('9', 'H'), ('9', 'S'), ('9', 'D'), ('9', 'C'), ('T', 'H'), ('T', 'C'), ('T', 'D'), ('T', 'S'), ('J', 'S'), ('J', 'C'), ('J', 'H'), ('J', 'D'), ('Q', 'H'), ('Q', 'C'), ('Q', 'D'), ('Q', 'S'), ('K', 'S'), ('K', 'H'), ('K', 'D'), ('K', 'C'), ('A', 'S'), ('A', 'D'), ('A', 'H'), ('A', 'C')]
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for. I just don't have enough experience with Python yet and especially the lambda function. This is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

```
ranks = "23456789TJQKA"

values = {'T': 10, 'J': 11, 'Q': 12, 'K': 13, 'A': 14}

cardDeck.sort(key=lambda c: int(c[0]) if '2' <= c[0] <= '9' else values[c[0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just sort according to the cards rank's index in the ranks string.

For example, an "A" is the 12 element and the "K" is the 11th element.  Therefore, all Aces come after Kings.
    import itertools

```
suits = "DCHS"
ranks = "23456789TJQKA"

cardDeck = list(set(itertools.product(ranks, suits)))

print sorted(cardDeck, key = lambda x: ranks.index(x[0]))
```

### Output

[('2', 'S'), ('2', 'C'), ('2', 'H'), ('2', 'D'), ('3', 'D'), ('3', 'H'), ('3', 'C'), ('3', 'S'), ('4', 'D')...